# What is the name of the part used to fasten a pendant light cable to the ceiling circuitry case

Tags: electrical, lighting, safety, plastic

I'm looking to purchase this part (see image below) but cannot find the name.

The part is located on the case mounted to the ceiling from which the cable to the pendant light comes down. One half is inside and the other on the outside of the case. It tightens the cable to the case so the cable cannot move up and down - otherwise potentially causing interference with the circuitry above.

The tip beyond the left thread tightens/holds the cable in place while screwing the cap on also secures it to the ceiling circuitry cover. I don't need the threads on the right side.

I bought a bunch of pendant lights but they were recalled due to missing these components and the potential safety issue mentioned above. Rather than removing and returning them I'd like to just add this piece.

**Q: What are these called?**

[image: Pendent light case fastener]

Comment: You will find these parts as `lamp cord grip bushing`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched "pendant lamp strain relief" and found all kinds of them with various names, such as "cable gland", "hanging lamp bushing", etc. Use your *Google Fu*, which is like Kung Fu for the Internet of Things.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I **like** google-fu and use it...

Comment: 'strain relief' was the keyword I didn't know. Thanks!